# Drools - How can we fire all rules from more than 1 .drl file

Tags: drools

I have 3 .drl files with 3 rules in each of them. I need to fire all rules within the drl files, given the same fact. Any idea how i can do that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you just need to create a single knowledge base with those three files. 
Use kbuilder.add() for each of your files and then create a session based on that knowledge base.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Put the 3 .drl files in a same knowledge base:

```
KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();

kbuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("rules/rulesA.drl"), ResourceType.DRL);
kbuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("rules/rulesB.drl"), ResourceType.DRL);
kbuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("rules/rulesC.drl"), ResourceType.DRL);

KnowledgeBase kbase = KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBase();
kbase.addKnowledgePackages(kbuilder.getKnowledgePackages());
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: is there anyway i can fire rules in any specific order ?

Comment: @DerickDaniel, this is not the place for starting new topics. If you think there is no other question in SO already covering the topic you are asking, then go ahead and create a new one.